# ReactJs not able to communicate between two components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react so apologies in advance if my question is silly.

**projects is an array Iam getting from App.js**

*(Project.js)*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProjectItem from './ProjectItem'

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    //====== PROJECTS IS AN ARRAY IAM GETTING FROM App.js====
    let projectItems;
    if(this.props.projects){
      projectItems = this.props.projects.map(project => {
        return(
          <ProjectItem key={project.title} project={project} />

        );
      }); // projects map end
    }//==if end
    // ====== RETURN PROJECTS ======
    return (
      <div className="Projects">
          <h1>Projects</h1>
          <p>{this.props.projects[0].title}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

**Here I am not able to get the props from Project.js**

*ProjectItem.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ProjectItem extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <li className="Project">
        {this.props.project.title}

      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectItem;
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you using `projectItems`? Looks like you are not using it.

Comment: You are not using `projectItems` inside the returned rendered component. You have to add it inside `<div className="Projects">`.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you would think that you have created the Projects list by mapping over the `projects array` but unless you return it from the Component, you will not be able to display the props.

You need to add `projectItems` to your return function like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProjectItem from './ProjectItem'

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    //====== PROJECTS IS AN ARRAY IAM GETTING FROM App.js====
    let projectItems;
    if(this.props.projects){
      projectItems = this.props.projects.map(project => {
        return(
          <ProjectItem key={project.title} project={project} />

        );
      }); // projects map end
    }//==if end
    // ====== RETURN PROJECTS ======
    return (
      <div className="Projects">
          <h1>Projects</h1>
          {projectItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```